# PHPMailer from Google users blocked by my Server?

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

Hi im using phpmailer in order to receive messages from my websites contact form.
Email is a required field.
I get all messages, even from fake email addresses, except gmail.
When the user insert a gmail address in email field the contact form responds that the message sent but the user receives the error below in their spam gmail folder:

```
The original message was received at Tue, 24 Sep 2013 12:08:21 -0700
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
  <info@mywebsitename.com>
  (reason: 553 sorry, your mail was administratively denied. (#5.7.1))

----- Transcript of session follows -----
  ... while talking to relay-hosting.secureserver.net.:
  MAIL From:<usernamemail@gmail.com> SIZE=1543 BODY=8BITMIME
  <<< 553 sorry, your mail was administratively denied. (#5.7.1)
  501 5.6.0 Data format error

Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.secureserver.net
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 12:08:21 -0700
Final-Recipient: RFC822; info@mywebsitename.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.3
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 553 sorry, your mail was administratively denied. (#5.7.1)
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 12:08:22 -0700
```

Well i seems my server refuses to send emails coming from gmail users. But why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i am answering my question.

Yes my server (godaddy) blocked gmail addresses.

As it seems also blocks yahoo, aol, live, hotmail and batch of others thats not "owned" registered domains, due to spam(as they say).

Well i changed the headers a bit.

```
$mail->SetFrom = 'info@myregistereddomain.com'
$mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
$mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
```

Now its working